# Rectangle draw call in mainActivity

Tags: android, canvas, draw

I draw a rectangle in the activity_main folder and I get these values to be drawn in integer.xml, but I do not want to do that.getInteger (R.integer.scanner_rect_width and getResources (). getInteger (R.integer.scanner_rect_height I get these values from the integer.xml folder, but how do I assign these values by creating a mainActivity object?

ScannerOverlay scannerOverlay = new ScannerOverlay (); as

ScanerOverlay.java

```
   public class ScannerOverlay extends ViewGroup {
private float left, top, endY;
private int rectWidth, rectHeight;
private int frames;
private boolean revAnimation;
private int lineColor, lineWidth;



public ScannerOverlay(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public void setWidth(int pixels) {
    rectWidth = pixels;
    requestLayout();
    invalidate();
}

public void setHeight(int pixels) {
    rectHeight = pixels;
    requestLayout();
    invalidate();
}

public ScannerOverlay(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public ScannerOverlay(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.ScannerOverlay,
            0, 0);
    rectWidth = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ScannerOverlay_square_width, 150);
    rectHeight = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ScannerOverlay_square_height, 150);
    lineColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.ScannerOverlay_line_color, ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.scanner_line));
    lineWidth = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ScannerOverlay_line_width, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.line_width));
    frames = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ScannerOverlay_line_speed, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.line_width));
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
public void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    left = (w - dpToPx(rectWidth)) / 2;
    top = (h - dpToPx(rectHeight)) / 2;
    endY = top;
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}

@Override
public boolean shouldDelayChildPressedState() {
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // draw transparent rect
    int cornerRadius = 0;
    Paint eraser = new Paint();
    eraser.setAntiAlias(true);
    eraser.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    RectF rect = new RectF(left, top, dpToPx(rectWidth) + left, dpToPx(rectHeight) + top);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, (float) cornerRadius, (float) cornerRadius, eraser);

    // draw horizontal line
    Paint line = new Paint();
    line.setColor(lineColor);
    line.setStrokeWidth(Float.valueOf(lineWidth));

    // draw the line to product animation
    if (endY >= top + dpToPx(rectHeight) + frames) {
        revAnimation = true;
    } else if (endY == top + frames) {
        revAnimation = false;
    }

    // check if the line has reached to bottom
    if (revAnimation) {
        endY -= frames;
    } else {
        endY += frames;
    }
    canvas.drawLine(left, endY, left + dpToPx(rectWidth), endY, line);
    invalidate();
}
   }
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="com.example.yavuz.myapplication.MainActivity">

<com.example.yavuz.myapplication.ScannerOverlay
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#44000000"
app:line_color="#7323DC"
app:line_speed="6"
app:line_width="4"
```

/>

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create setters methods for width and height as below:

```
public void setWidth(int pixels) {
        rectWidth = pixels;
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
}

public void setHeight(int pixels) {
        rectHeight = pixels;
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
}
```

Then to use it MainActivity you use it as below:

```
ScannerOverlay scannerOverlay = new ScannerOverlay();
scannerOverlay.setWidth(200); // for example
scannerOverlay.setHeight(300);

setContentView(scannerOverlay);
```

I suppose that ScannerOverlay is a custom view.

from xml layout:

```
<thepackage_where_theclass.ScannerOverlay
app:scanner_rect_width="200"
app:scanner_rect_height="200"/>
```

Comment: I shared the source code below for better understanding. Thanks for the codes, but how can I get R.integer.scanner_rect_width, R.integer.scanner_rect_height from main class?

Comment: my answer is suitable when you want to set with and height programatically. to get the width and height through the way you followed you have to pass them from the layout. I updated my answer for that. Please note that you have to replace thepackage_where_theclass with the package name when ScannerOverlay is created

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. but I can look for updated responsibilities. How can I call the 150,150 value in MainActivity when I write in ScannerOverlay class? I'm looking for it